# Using Batch request in PHP SDK to get Facebook Album Covers

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-batch-request

I am using the PHP SDK through Batch Request (so that its faster to get the covers of all the albums). Its working fine, but the pictures I am getting are not the album covers but the individual pictures in the various cropped sizes.

```
$albums_resp = $facebook->api('/'.$fbid.'/albums','GET');
$albums = $albums_resp['data'];

//prepare batch query for album covers
$queries = array ();    
foreach ($albums as $album)
{
    if ($album['cover_photo'] != null)
    {
        $query = array('method' => 'GET', 'relative_url' => $album['cover_photo']);
        array_push($queries, $query);
    }
}

$queries_str = json_encode($queries);
$batchResponse = $facebook->api('?batch='.$queries_str, 'POST');
```

I know that there is another way by using the URL `/{albumID}/picture?type=small` as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169543/facebook-php-sdk-getting-cropped-album-cover) but I still can't get the same image sizes facebook shows in covers (I tried `thumbnail`, `small`, `cover`), and when I use this approach in a batch request for all albums I don't seem to have any way to correlate the response with the album ID. What I get in response is a redirect status 302 with the location of the image.

I don't want to put the image links directly `/{albumID}/picture?type=small` either because if there are 25 albums it means 25 image redirects, making the page slow.

Comment: is it working fine now ? I need to use this.

Comment: Yes. Just posted the code I built to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did in the end is use the `cover_photo` ID to get the full image information (which includes the URLs of the image in different sizes and also the ID itself) and correlated that with the album's cover photo ID.

```
$cover_photos = array();
foreach ($batchResponse as $cover_photo_resp)
{   
    if ($cover_photo_resp['code'] == 200)
    {
        $cover_photo = json_decode($cover_photo_resp['body'], true);    
        $cover_photos[$cover_photo['id']] = $cover_photo;
    }
}

//correlate the cover photos with the respective albums, according to the cover photo ID
for ($i = 0; $i < count($albums); $i++)
{
    $albums[$i]['cover_photo_obj'] = $cover_photos[$albums[$i]['cover_photo']]; 
}
```

What you end up in the end is the `$albums[]` array of associative arrays each with an extra field in each album referring to the `cover_photo_obj` object with all the information about the cover photo.

Comment: You can set the cover photo in the same foreach loop using the index. Example foreach ($batchResponse as $i=>$cover_photo_resp)